# Trouble running Laravel 5 Server. "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Tags: php, laravel

I decided to commit to learning PHP and I had TONS of trouble installing Laravel on Ubuntu but I am finally up and running. However, whenever I run `php artisan serve` I get [this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsxF3.png).

I think I may have changed the host file, but not sure. I don't quite understand the host files or where do access them. Nonetheless, in NodeJS, when creating an Express JS server, we used to do something like `app.listen(3000);` but I don't see where Laravel is getting the URL.

I also tried `php artisan key:generate` but it says

```
  [ErrorException]                                                             
  file_get_contents(/home/user/Documents/laraveltut/.env): failed to o  
  pen stream: No such file or directory
```

even though I have changed the `.env.example` to `.env`. This is what my `.env` file looks like.

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

It's just overwhelming because I am following a tutorial that has a slightly lower version, but I can't get anything working. Not to mention, I haven't even go ahold of VirtualBox or Vagrant whatever those are.

Comment: Is the `.env` file in the same directory as the `artisan` file?

Answer (score 1):

Look in your log files to identify specific error. The screenshot is the generic error message. Your log file `/laravel/app/storage/logs/laravel.log` (or someplace else if you've configured it differently) will contain the actual error and trace.

The second error indicates the file `/home/user/Documents/laraveltut/.env` does not exist. So is that path correct?

Comment: My logs only has a `.gitignore` and the path is correct.

Comment: If the path were correct, PHP wouldn't fail to open it. Maybe it has incorrect permissions or incorrect owner/group, but the error `failed to open stream: No such file or directory` indicates PHP can't find anything at that path.

Comment: Do you know where PHP logs to? If you can find your Apache (or Nginx or whatever httpd server you're using) logs, you can look there to see if PHP errors are logged there.

Comment: I am such an idiot, I had the wrong Laravel project open. The current one does not have `.env` file whatsoever. Should I go ahead and create one? And yes, there is a `laravel.log` in this project. Hahaha

Comment: Ha! An easy oversight : ) Yes you will want to create your env file in the correct project folder.

Comment: And when I ran `php artisan key:generate` it gave me...
`Application key [base64:CSyxC+T6XA8rlP10YsJ+GBtbZfbS`. But the serve is still not running. Hmmm...

Comment: Fixed it. I just pasted the entire `.env` file from the other one to this... LOL. Still have no idea what I am doing, but that's life!

Comment: Glad you got it working! Setting up a Ubuntu box for LAMP server AND learning Laravel along the way, easier said than done. Stick with it & come back here for help :}